# Is RestTemplate instance heavy weight object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have Spring MVC Project which is a client of different API services. This services have different request and response format.

What is a better idea:
To have one RestTemplate bean that is configured per request (e.g. different headers are set), or to have different RestTemplate objects per specific need that is fully configured during initialization?

Comment: I think it will depend a bit on the actual services being called, and how similar/different the calling conventions are. On a project I recently did with a similar need, I liked having one `RestTemplate` per service, and injecting them into wrapper objects that encapsulated the service-specific details (really just message converters and error handlers). My app code only dealt with POJO service classes; the service classes deals with API keys, authentication, error handling, header/type mapping, etc.

Comment: @bimsapi could you elaborate a bit more ? a sample service class ?

Comment: @Nati - two examples from the project: a service class for sending SMS messages wrapping Twilio's RESTful API, and a service class for sending transactional emails via SendGrid's RESTful API. Both services instantiated their own RestTemplate classes. Worrying about synchronization for a shared RestTemplate seems like premature optimization vs. taking a small hit in the RestTemplate. The bulk of any performance concern will be with the REST call itself.

Comment: @bimsapi - Thanks. that does clear some things. Just last thing - do you `new` or `@Inject` those `RestTemplate`s ?